# How to select the split point for Continuous Attribute Age

Tags: classification, decision-trees

[image]

For the above table, midpoints for possible split points are 22.5 and 35. I have calculated the entropy and gain for each value and 35 had the minimum Entropy and highest gain. Is it correct ?

Given *High* -> (-), and *Low* -> (+)

D<22.5 => [0+, 2-],
Entropy (D<22.5) = 0, since all the values are of the same class *High*.

D>22.5 => [2+, 2-],
Entropy (D>22.5) = 1, since the values are distributed equally among *Low* and *High* classes.

D<35 => [2+, 3-],
Entropy (D<35) = -[2/6 x $log_2$(2/6) + 3/6 x $log_2$⁡(3/6)]= 0.5

D>35 => [0+, 1-],
Entropy (D>35) = 0, since all the values are of the same class *High*

Gain (D, Age>22.5) = 0.918 - 2/6 (0) - 4/6 (1) = 0.2513

Gain (D, Age>35) = 0.918 - 5/6 (0.5) - 1/6 (0) = 0.5103

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 35 split, there is an error in the denominator. It should be 5 as the total number of items for D<35 is 5

> D<35 => [2+, 3-], Entropy (D<35) = -[2/**5** x $log_2$(2/**5**) + 3/**5** x $log_2$⁡(3/**5**)]

Comment: Thank you jdsuryap , this was helpful. Is correct to say that though the Entropy of D<22.5 is higher than Entropy of D<35; however the gain for D<22.5 is higher.

Comment: Perhaps not @Ali. If you would try fixing the error as I proposed, the correct entropy of 35 split is higher. Hence, the information gain for split 22.5 is higher.

Comment: Thank you. I did already. Entropy (D<35) = -[2/5 x 〖log_2 (〗⁡〖2/5)〗+3/5 x 〖log_2 (〗⁡〖3/5)〗 ]= 0.9709       D<35  [2+, 3-] . So the Entropy of 22.5 is 1 and Entropy of 35 is 09709 however the gain for 22.5 will be higher though its entropy is lower.